# Set current time field for MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, timestamp

I am trying to set the value of a field via a hidden form field to the current date and time using either PHP or Javascript that would conform to MySQL's datetime field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use PHP to get and format the current system date/time for use in MySQL like this:

```
$now = date('Y-m-d H-i-s');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can directly set current date and time in your SQL insert query using `NOW()`:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (current_time, column2, column3,...) 
VALUES (NOW(), value2, value3,...)
```

where `current_time` is the field where you want to put current date and time.

Answer (score 2):

Create the column using `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Those together will make it so that any new rows inserted have the current time and are updated again when the column is updated.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE test (last_modified TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Edit: Nevermind, this will use a `TIMESTAMP` column, not DATETIME.  Other answers will do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php echo time(); ?>
```

will output a nice simple integer number that you can pass directly into MySQL and convert into a native mysql datetime value with `FROM_UNIXTIME()`. It'll save you the trouble of formatting the data in a nice `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` string.

Comment: you'd have to do a `INSERT (datefield) VALUES (FROM_UNIXTIME($timefield))` type of thing. It's just an integer, and you have to explicitly tell MySQL that it should be treated as a timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

$current = date_timestamp_set(date_create(), time());